# Best Way to query on dates ot of two different rows (BigQuery)

Tags: google-bigquery

As a data analyst, I work on a BigQuery environment. The tables we use all have new records for every update of the object we study. For instance here is a example of our Customer table :

| Obs | CustomerName | NumberOfItems | UpdateDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 0 | 2020-11-04 |
| 2 | John | 4 | 2020-12-25 |
| 3 | John | 5 | 2021-02-10 |
| 4 | John | 8 | 2021-04-23 |
| 5 | Anna | 2 | 2020-12-15 |
| 6 | Anna | 6 | 2021-03-12 |

Business users often ask the same question : what was the state at a specific date.
For example : Tell me how many items had John on the first day of 2021. The answer is 4.

I'm currently using the LAG function to retrieve the UpdateDate from previous observation partitioning by CustomerName.
But it doesn't look efficient at all.

I could also select where UpdateDate <= '2021-01'01' and keep the MAX(UpdateDate) but this doesn't look efficient either.

How can effeciently retrieve observations between two dates on two different row of a same customer ?

Do you have better recommandations ?
Do the table I work on has a missing field such as UpdateDateLastObs ?
Is it a table modeling problem ?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Why do you think those methods are not efficient?

Comment: It seems very handiwork, doesn't it ? i'm thinking maybe i am missing a feature that is often used or maybe the table schema is not appropriate.